# XCode global search (cmd + shift + f) include storyboard source code

Tags: ios, xcode, search, storyboard, xcode-storyboard

How can I search globally (cmd + shift + f) on XCode that included the texts in the storyboard or xib's source code?

Here's my example

[image]

I searched the `<dependencies>` text in global search but it return 0 results.

I want to search that text in every file on my project.